# Rails4: Optional parameters in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have a Rails4 model (`my_model`) which may or may not have an attribute. I don't want to save the attribute on my db after I call:

`my_model.save`

or

`my_model.create`

but I would like to have access to the value of this possible attribute (or nil if it doesn't exist) after doing:

`my_model.new(attribute: possible_attribute)`

Is there a way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `possible_attribut`e as `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessibl`e

```
class MyModel
  attr_accessor :possible_attribute
  attr_accessible :possible_attribute
end
```

Now you can do

```
m = MyModel.new(:possible_attribute => "value")
m.possible_attribute #value
```

And

```
m.save
```

will not save `possible_attribute`